# Retrieving users password from Django and passing as variable to log in to Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django powered web-app which also utilizes the Django REST framework. I want to read and write to my database using the API generated by Django REST.
I can do this successfully when I hardcode the password of the current user, but I can't do this when I attempt to pass in the retrieved password from Django, as Django does not store the password as plain text. (I know I can change this, but I am hoping there is a better way).

Essentially, my logic flow is this:

1. user logs in using Django login form
2. user would like to write new data to database, but will need API token
3. Obtain API token (already generated when they sign up)
4. use this token to authenticate and POST JSON data to REST framework

I can do all of these steps above when I hardcode the password as plain text in my script, but I would like to "retrieve" the password and pass it automatically if possible.

**Code below works as described above:**

**views.py**

```
class DefaultsListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams
    template_name = 'defaults_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams.objects.filter
        (customerTag=self.request.user.customerTag)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        testing = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        userName = str(self.request.user.username)
        passWord = str(self.request.user.password)
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/'
        context = {'tokenURL': url, 'user':userName, 'pass':passWord}
        return context
```

**template.html**

```
<div class = "debugging">
  <p id = "csrf">{% csrf_token %}</p>
  <p id = "tokenURL">{{tokenURL}}</p>
  <p id = "user">{{user}}</p>
  <p id = "pass">{{pass}}</p>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
var csrfToken = document.querySelector("#csrf input").value;
var user = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/";
xhr.open("POST", url,);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-CSRFToken", csrfToken);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.token);
    }
};
var data = JSON.stringify({"username": user, "password": 'myhardcodedpass' });
xhr.send(data);
```

This script will log the API token of the current user to the console as expected. But instead of hardcoding the password, I would like to just pass it as a variable, but the password is a very long string as it is not stored as plain text (var pass). So trying to use pass is rejected, as it obviously isn't the correct password when passed as text.

Is there a way to decrypt this password, or translate it somehow? Or perhaps an easier way to retrieve the API token from Django REST?

Comment: Unless you _have_ to use auth tokens, use cookies and sessions instead.  Sessions are browser controlled authentication tokens with a timeout.  Unless you have a mobile app or some other non-browser device talking to your backend, just use sessions and cookies.  I do this with DRF myself.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you should definitely NOT store the password as plain text. That is never the solution in any case, and only will cause problems.

I have a few suggestions that you can potentially use, but the easiest would be to simply use a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/) which can easily be integrated with Django Rest Framework using the [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) library.

Your workflow would basically be as follows:

1. User logs in successfully, which returns a JWT to authenticate the user
2. The script would be included in the header of the request, and the middleware would be able to successfully identify and authenticate the user.

Hopefully this gives you an idea on how to move forward. Best of luck